# instantiateControllerWithIdentifier always return nil

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I try to choose an instance NSCollectionView item from the storyboard and fail. Always receive nil.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSCollectionViewItem *collectionViewItem = [self.storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"collectionItem"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Probably I don't know where to set the identifier "collectionItem", directly on NSCollectionViewItem or NSView in NSCollectionViewItem. For NSCollectionViewItem I did not find the identifier. There is only a Storyboard ID or ID Restoration and neither worked. I am using Xcode 6.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should to initialize a ViewController after that when all views are loaded, so call super before it.

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboardName" bundle:nil];
     UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardID"];
```

`}`

Be sure that you set 'storyboardID' properly

Comment: UIStoryboard and UIViewController is deprecated for me. I must change to NSStoryboard and NSViewController but my code works too, when i initiaze super before and NSCollectionViewItem was nil because i have bad  position of breakpoint :X